# Type text from external keyboard using App

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, keyboard, p2p

I've an App on my iPhone that communicates with a companion app on my mac.

Now the app on the mac get data from the one on the phone to perform specific action. Is there a way to let this app tell the mac to type text even outside the app?

I'll explain myself with an example:

I launch the 2 apps, then I select the text field for the link on safari. I now press the A `UIButton` on my phone app that sends a message to the app in background on the mac telling I've pressed that button.

Now what i want is that the app on the mac will type A on the search bar in safari.

Edit Code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, MessageServiceManagerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: NSTextField!


var service = MessageServiceManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    service = MessageServiceManager()
    service.delegate = self
    // Do view setup here.
}

func connectedDevicesChanged(manager : MessageServiceManager, connectedDevices: [String]){}

func messageReceived(manager : MessageServiceManager, message: String){

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myLabel.stringValue = message
    }   
}    
}
```

This is the macOS part of the 2 apps in the `messageReceived` func i want the app to type the letter (now i just set a `Label` to the button pressed on the phone)

Comment: Share code if you need help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.